# How to filter the results of a pandas groupby function based off a substring contained in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of employees who have completed a bunch of trainings and I have to find out who has completed onboarding. I have two columns:

| EmployeeID | CompletedCourseName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | onboarding part 1 |
| 1 | onboarding part 2 |
| 1 | corporate compliance training A |
| 2 | corporate compliance training B |
| 2 | random other training |

In order to be classified as having "completed onboarding" they need to have completed both the onboarding part 1  (Part 2 isn't necessary) and at least 1 of the corporate compliance trainings. The simplest way to do this conceptually, to me, is to groupby the patient ID and return True if the CompletedCourseName string series contains "onboarding part 1" and "corporate compliance". But I'm wondering if there's a more pythonic or "pandanic" way to do this.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
data = [
    {"EmployeeID": 1, "CompletedCourseName ": "onboarding part 1"},
    {"EmployeeID": 1, "CompletedCourseName ": "onboarding part 2"},
    {"EmployeeID": 1, "CompletedCourseName ": "corporate compliance training A"},
    {"EmployeeID": 2, "CompletedCourseName ": "corporate compliance training B"},
    {"EmployeeID": 2, "CompletedCourseName ": "Random other Training"}
]

# Create a DataFrame from the list
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# return True if True is anywhere in the returned series of Trues and Falses that was return after checking if the required substring exists.
df.groupby(['EmployeeID'])['CompletedCourseName '].apply(lambda column: 
( True in list(column.str.lower().str.contains("onboarding part 1")) ) 
& 
( True in list(column.str.lower().str.contains("corporate compliance"))  )  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting boolean series to lists and then checking if True is in the list, you can directly apply the logical conditions on the boolean series. Try this :

```
# Group by EmployeeID and check if both conditions are satisfied
onboarding_completion = df.groupby('EmployeeID')['CompletedCourseName'].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains('onboarding part 1', case=False).any() 
              and 
              x.str.contains('corporate compliance', case=False).any()
)

print(onboarding_completion)
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic and efficient approach that lets you combine as many conditions as you want:

```
# set up condtions
c1 = df['CompletedCourseName '].str.contains('onboarding part 1', case=False)
c2 = df['CompletedCourseName '].str.contains('corporate compliance training', case=False)

# concat, groupby.any, all
out = (pd.concat([c1, c2], axis=1)         # combine conditions
         .groupby(df['EmployeeID']).any()  # check if each is met once
         .all(axis=1)                      # check if all are met
      )
```

Output:

```
EmployeeID
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Intermediate before the last `all(axis=1)` (with custom names):

```
               c1    c2
EmployeeID             
1            True  True
2           False  True
```

Comment: The .any() check if theres "any" Trues, correct? What does the .all() do?

Comment: the `any` check if there each row is matching a given condition (e.g. "onboarding part 1") for a given user. Then `all` checks that a user fulfilled all conditions.

Comment: I wonder which is faster, your answer or TheHungryCub's answer

Comment: @YisroelLen depends how you time it. For a few groups it's similar, when you have many groups (tested on 50k rows and 5000 groups) then mine is `34.5 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop` and the other `950 ms ± 18.6 ms per loop`. For 500k rows 100k IDs, it's `359 ms ± 24.4 ms` vs `18.9 s ± 297 ms`.